# Overwrite nginx html directory in Docker compose configuration

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I just started working with docker and am quite enthusiastic so far! At the moment, I am trying to build an extremely basic and extendable file that just serves basic static websites. I figured that this shouldn't be so difficult, but I have the following problem:

The following `docker-compose.yml` file still shows the default nginx `index.html` file, I expected that this would be overwritten by my project folder `./code`. Can I overwrite all files in `/usr/share/nginx/html` without adding a separate `Dockerfile`? I am trying to keep this configuration as minimal as possible.

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html

  // Whenever needed php/python/dababase services can be added here
```

Comment: I've just tested your compose file as-is and it worked as expected. I created a simple index.html file in a ./code directory. Stop and start your Docker service and see if that resolves it; I've unfortunately had similar problems that a stop and start resolved.

Comment: Hmm strange, I only see the 'Welcome to nginx!' html file. Also after restarting my service.

Comment: The only thing I can think of after that would be that your ./code file is not at the same level as your docker-compose.yml file.  Try placing a full path instead of the relative `./code` and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I got it working by adding the `:z` label on my volumes command. So the last line in my code became:

`- ./code:/usr/share/nginx/html:z`

According to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) the labels :z and :Z change the label in the container context. These suffixes tell Docker to relabel file objects on the shared volumes. The `:z` option tells Docker that two containers share the volume content. As a result, Docker labels the content with a shared content label. Shared volume labels allow all containers to read/write content. The `:Z` option tells Docker to label the content with a private unshared label. Only the current container can use a private volume.